# Exchange Hybrid SMTP High Availability

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-hybrid

I have been asked to setup exchange hybrid but I must have 2 Exchange Hybrid servers handling mail flow and mailbox migrations. Is it possible to deploy 2 Hybrid servers that are load balanced and have SMTP high availability - meaning if one hybrid is down, mail flow will still continue with the secondary hybrid server with a F5 switch over.

Would this require four send and receive connectors on both sides?  send / receive on Hybrid1 and send / receive on Hybrid2.
Using the following host records and adding these into the certificate SAN
1) smtp1.contoso.com
2) smtp2.contoso.com

I know that this is not ideal but unfortunately the IT manager wants it like that. Please advice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no “hybrid server”, the hybrid configuration is for the whole Exchange organization. 
So you could select one or more Exchange servers to host the connectors, and you also could use WNLB or HLB in order to provide high availability on the identity federation level.